# How to use AutoMapper to create mapping from single class to nested class

Tags: automapper

My class structure looks like this. What I'm trying to do is, create automap from source EmployeeInfo class to destination NewEmployeeInfo class and vise Versa.

```
public class EmployeeInfo ///// Old Employee class - Transform this into New
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}

public class NewEmployeeInfo //// New Employee -- Transform in to this
{
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the example provided in the link source is NewEmployeeInfo and the destination is EmployeeInfo. But I want the other way around means my source is EmployeeInfo and destination is NewEmployeeInfo.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html

Comment: Great!!! Working as expected. Thanks a ton for the quick response.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu i guess you can add the documentation as an answer, or this question is simply invalid, coz it can be solved from docs